# How do I cast a "string" into a "option<string>"

Tags: f#

I have a function declared as

```
let GetLength (value : option<string>) = 
    if value.IsSome then value.Value.Length else 0
```

And I have the variable

```
let a : string = "tom"
```

How do I pass a to the function GetLength?

Comment: Idiomatically, you don't write .IsSome and .Value, instead you use a 'match' statement.

Comment: Based on your series of questions today, you may find it useful to read http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!180.entry and http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!181.entry , which provide a storytelling motivation for the option type.

Comment: That won't last. Why would anyone willing type 18 tokens over 3 lines when you can get the exact same thing using 12 tokens on one line?

Comment: I'm glad someone is pointing out some of the inflexibilities in F#. I know it's functional and all, but I would like it to take a more pragmatic approach and leave some of the purist ideologies behind. If I could add/remove 5 or 6 features from the language, it would definitely be my favorite one. So far, it's not.

Comment: @sker, You wouldn't believe the amount of pushback I'm getting for it. I though C# fans were bad when it got optional parameters, but the F# crowd are downright fanatical about not questioning it. It is a real shame because F# could be so much more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't cast it. You need to use the `Some` constructor:

```
GetLength Some a
```

Comment: Well that is stupid. Clearly any string value will meet the requirements of an option<string>. I shouldn't have to explicitly make that conversion.

Comment: @Grauenwolf: it may be worth spending some time learning how to write idiomatic F# code before criticizing too harshly.  I think you'll find that although it's often different from typical C# or VB.NET code, there's a reason why things were designed as they are...

Comment: It's only inconsistent if you insist of thinking of option<'a> as Nullable<T>, I thouht we'd already established it's not. option<'a> is just a type define it the F# libraries, the compiler does not treat it as a special case.

Comment: @Robert: But should it treat it as a special case? Would we lose anything if the compiler was smart enough to see that for any variable a, it is always safe to convert it into Some(a)?

Comment: @kvb: Well? Don't just leave me hanging. Tell me why that conversion shouldn't be done automatically.

Comment: @Grauenwolf: Well, one reason is that type inference is a lot easier if you don't try to apply automatic conversions.  F# also won't automatically convert from an int to a long, even though it's a safe widening conversion, and the reason is the same.  How hard is it to wrap your value in the Some constructor?  To me, it's well worth the tradeoff for type inference and consistency.  I consider it a feature that the "string option" type is not treated specially and that I could create an analogous type myself and have it work in exactly the same way.

Comment: The compiler doesn't treat it differently because it doesn't need to. It is only 4 extra characters. It also make type inference possible, which means you have to type a lot less in many other cases. So, no, it's definitely not stupid. Don't expect it to be like C#.

Comment: There is no implicit conversion at all in F#. You cannot pass '0' as a byte without either explicitly converting it with 'byte', or adding the special suffix 'uy'. Also, 'option' is just an everyday union type. What if the union had multiple similar values (Ex: type MyType<'a> = Type1 of 'a | Type2 of 'a) and a function was expecting such a value? Would the compiler convert your 'a using the Type1 or Type2 constructors? Maybe some day the class designers will be able to declare implicit operations (like in C#) but I haven't heard anything of the sort.

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer doesn't compile, and produces...

```
GetLength Some a;;
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  error FS0003: This value is not a function and cannot be applied

F# thinks you are building a function `(GetLength Some)` to apply to the value `a`. That is because it's a functional language.

The correct form is

```
GetLength (Some a);;
```

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to parentheses:

```
GetLength <| Some a
```

I think it's important to address this question:

> Why would anyone willing type 18
>   tokens over 3 lines when you can get
>   the exact same thing using 12 tokens
>   on one line?

Writing code isn't just about conciseness - it's also about readability and maintainability. Suppose you need to handle the case where `a` is `null`. With pattern matching, you could go from this:

```
let GetLength (value : string option) =
    match value with
    | Some s -> s.Length
    | _ -> 0
```

To this:

```
let GetLength (value : string option) =
    match value with
    | Some s when s <> null -> s.Length
    | _ -> 0
```

To an F# programmer, the meaning is clear. To fix your implementation would look something like this:

```
let GetLength (value : option<string>) = 
    if value.IsSome && value.Value <> null then value.Value.Length else 0
```

The result might be the same, but I don't find it particularly easy to see, at a glance, what's happening.

It's fine if pattern matching doesn't resonate with you, but the extra "cost" in the simple case is often made up for many times over as the logic evolves.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the general question of casting `'a` to `option<'a>`, if you wanted to do it safely without just applying the object to the `Some` constructor, there is a simple function that I would use:

```
let to_option = function
  | null -> None
  | obj -> Some obj
```